# AWS Delete everything contained in a folder using the PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, delete-file

I would like to know why my simple code, is not deleting from a bucket everthing contained in `rave/fool`

My code:

```
$result = $s3Client->deleteObjects([
    'Bucket' => 'mybucket',
    'Delete' => [
        'Objects' => [
            [
                'Key' => 'rave/fool/*',
            ],
            
        ],
        'Quiet' => true,
    ],
]);
```

It should delete every item contained in `rave/fool/` cause I have a crazy amout of data that I would like to delete on a batch operation.

Thanks again, and great community.

Answer (score 2):

S3 does not have wildcards. The asterisk is being viewed as a literal character in a key (and presumably there is no object that matches that key).

You can list all objects with the relevant prefix (`rave/fool/`) and delete them one-by-one or in batches.

Update: it looks like the AWS PHP SDK includes a shortcut for this functionality: [deleteMatchingObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.S3.S3ClientInterface.html#_deleteMatchingObjects), but don't use the asterisk when you specify the prefix. You can also supply a regular expression and it will delete only objects that match the regex.

Comment: i already got that, thanks for that @jarmod

Comment: Actually, take a look at [deleteMatchingObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.S3.S3ClientInterface.html#_deleteMatchingObjects), but don't use the asterisk.